# Is it possible to pause a video at intervals, and request a Captcha to continue playing?

Tags: javascript, video, captcha

YouTube, Vimeo or any other video service will do. I'm looking for a way of knowing that there is definitely a person watching a video. So far my best idea is to request a Captcha at intervals (say 30 seconds)... Is this possible?

Comment: Why, just why? If you have to, ask for captcha at the beginning and then play the video. If you will ask every 30s, no one will watch the videos, ever. I know this isn't helpful, but I don't care, it had to be said.

Comment: @maremp I haven't given the full picture here. You're right it does sound like an odd idea without any context.

Comment: I don't think there justification, except if user get paid for watching. And even then, it's nothing worse than distracting a user in the middle of watching, you lose all their attention.

Comment: Yeah this sounds like a terrible user experience, its not enough to check there's s human at the start?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Any video player api will let you check the player state, the current playing time, and allow you to pause, play, and stop the video. You could use setInterval to check if the video is playing and that 30 seconds have passed, in that case you could pause the video, show your captcha and continue playing if the captcha was resolved successfully.

Check out the youtube api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
or jwplayer api: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Comment: Although I agree with @maremp showing a captcha makes horrible UX, let alone stoping the video at 30s...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it will bring down the user experience in doing so. Even Google is trying to replace "captcha" concept with other interactive methods to enhance the user experience.

Alternatively, you may request user to register/login prior playing the video to prevent any robotic access.

Answer (score 0):

If you pay the user for watching the video then the user is highly motivated to make some RoboForm earn more money. To register/login, the user can use some RPA solution like BluePrism or UIPath. It will take a couple of hours to make the script and infinite money flow is guaranteed before the ban.
In this case, pausing the video at some nonstandard interval and requesting some sort of captcha to see if "someone alive is out there" is not a very user-friendly solution but very effective.
JW Player API allows pausing the video and restart it. You can hide controls and disable keyboard controls to ensure user to watch all the video. You can pause the video, show overlay window with captcha to continue watching. The server will know the video is paused.
To ensure that the user is not loading your JS from his own source you can add some token to the path and check it in different ways on the server-side when client-side do some requests.